# Jenkins plugin - how to create multiple pages for displaying report

Tags: jenkins

I'm developing a Jenkins plugin for displaying reports of my own tool. I got difficulties because Jenkins lacks documentation for developing plugins. Currently, my plugin can only display report on a build page

Screenshoot (surroneded by red border):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMj4Z.jpg

But I want multi-page reports like the Junit plugins on this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWw9AQqUAGU&t=174s (2:56)

How to make a Jenkins plugin that can display reports on multiple pages?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go through the JUnit Plugin code below is the starting point to dig into it.
[TestResultAction](https://github.com/jenkinsci/junit-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/junit/TestResultAction.java)

Refer the below link for an article for you to start.
[jenkins-plugin-development](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/02/tutorial-jenkins-plugin-development/)

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished this by utilizing ANT build scripts which generate HTML report files after running all of my JUnits.

You could simply publish JUnit results (represented in HTML files) to a public_html directory on a web server which can then be accessed via web browser, displayed on Jenkins dashboards via iframe, etc

Just add [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin) and publish the JUnit results.